# how to get facebook user events in Python 3 with user token?

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, web-services, events, get

I want to get facebook user events list.

I generated user token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ ,
and now i am trying to create get request with python to facebook,
is it accessible?

this is my code

```
import facebook
raph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='sometoken', version="3.0")
pages_data = graph.get_object("/me/events")
print(pages_data)
```

but this is what i will get, is this some unicode? or is this right way to get events? i am newbie and need help

[image]

Comment: Whose idea was _that_ API? It looks like you're using it fine, but that it's a bad API. (Also, are you _sure_ that you're using Python 3? That `u"string"` notation looks like Python 2.)

Comment: ups you are right, this is what print(sys.version) did, what can i do?

     2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 14 2019, 15:42:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Anaconda?! Yeugh. Download real Python (Python 3, this time) from <https://python.org>, and install the Facebook module from `pip`.